# Oreo Widget freezing

Tags: android, android-widget, android-8.1-oreo

I have a widget that works great at all versions < Oreo.
The widget layout includes buttons + list.
In oreo I have some problems. 
When I open another app and then go back to the widget, it resets the data in the list (and shows empty white list) and the buttons are not responding to click.
When I click on a button, it resizes the widget size.
For click binding - I am using an pendingIntent that points to the AppWidgetProvider.

Comment: My widget's buttons don't work either on Oreo+. Did you find a solution to your problem ?

Comment: Actually I have found a solution. If you rotate the home screen, the android launcher builds a new widget instance from your last submitted remote view. Therefore, if you perform partial update of the remote view, you may get invalid widget instance. So my solution was to perform only full update every time. –